# Woocommerce Pre Orders view order link wrong

Tags: order, woocommerce-offtopic, pre

The link that the pre order module produces in My Account doesn't work. It has to display like this: /my-account/view-order/15977 but how it displays now is: /my-account/?order=15977. How can i change that link to my structure.

This is the piece of code which displays it:

```
            <td class="order-number" width="1%">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'order', $order->id, get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'view_order' ) ) ) ); ?>"><?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?></a>
            </td>
```

i also want it to be update proof ofcourse so how can i make a "child plugin".

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

```
<td class="order-number" width="1%">
    <a href="<?php echo wc_get_endpoint_url( 'view-order', $order->id, wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ); ?>">
    <?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?></a>
</td>;
```

this should solve your problem.

But I am not sure which template your are modifying, but fool proof way is only possible with child theme (functionality plugin will be complex for your needs).

https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203105897-How-to-set-up-and-use-a-child-theme

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

both of these should help you get started with child theme.

**Note:** Make sure you permalinks are set to Pretty permalink not default under section

*WP Admin -> Settings -> Permalink -> Go to section named "Product permalink base"* and make sure of that.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm copied the file: /woocommerce-pre-orders/templates/myaccount/my-pre-orders.php to my child theme with the same structure and edited the piece of code you put here. But it doesn't change a thing.. Do i need to put a piece of code in functions.php to read the custom code?

Comment: Did you check permalinks setting on Dashboard?

Comment: Also make sure, your template is being overridden properly,
by visiting Dashboard -> WooCommerce -> System Settings -> Templates Section if not, than you need to rename the folder used for Pre Orders templates.

Comment: The thing is it's a seperate plugin called: woocommerce-pre-orders so it's not inside the woocommerce folder

Comment: What I mean't was by default for most extensions files goes into "woocommerce" folder inside themes, but some plugins / extensions might require different path than "woocommerce" folder.

To make sure, Dashboard -> WooCommerce -> System Settings -> Templates and it will show you if relevant template is overridden or not. If not than you are using incorrect path.

To test the code, you can just put it directly in plugins template for testing purposes whether it works or not.

Than you can make sure you are overriding templates properly or not.

Comment: And how do i override the template files of a plugin? I already copied the same structure to my child theme. There is no file of the plugin in the woocommerce folder so i cannot see if it's overridden in Dashboard -> WooCommerce -> System Settings -> Templates. Since it's not in the WooCommerce folder. So my question is how do i override a plugin what's not inside the woocommerce folder

Comment: Please follow these two links

https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203105897-How-to-set-up-and-use-a-child-theme

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

and you will know which files to copy to theme in order to make customization's

Comment: Those links are to override WooCommerce, not to override the plugin woocommerce-pre-orders

Comment: Those links are good for any extensions you use from WooThemes for WooCommerce plugin.